# Why is the Python version of itertools.islice not working?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have noticed that Recipes section in the `itertools` documentation has some useful code, like `consume`, but I have found a problem.

```
from itertools import islice
numbers = iter(range(10))
for i in numbers:
    print i 
    next(islice(numbers, 3, 3), None)
```

the code above works fine, it prints `[0,4,8]`, the `next(islice(numbers, 3, 3), None)` trick is taken from the `consume` recipe.

We can see `islice` here is playing an important role. But, when I replace `itertools.islice` with the code provided in python documentation for that function, the code is not working as I expected:

```
#from itertools import islice

def islice(iterable, *args):
    # islice('ABCDEFG', 2) --> A B
    # islice('ABCDEFG', 2, 4) --> C D
    # islice('ABCDEFG', 2, None) --> C D E F G
    # islice('ABCDEFG', 0, None, 2) --> A C E G
    s = slice(*args)
    it = iter(xrange(s.start or 0, s.stop or 200, s.step or 1))
    nexti = next(it)
    for i, element in enumerate(iterable):
        if i == nexti:
            yield element
            nexti = next(it)


numbers = iter(range(10))
for i in numbers:
    print i 
    next(islice(numbers, 3, 3), None)
```

the output is different from the output above; *all* numbers in the range are printed and the `islice()` consume line doesn't appear to do anything.

Can anybody can explain why this is and the way `islice` works here?

Comment: does it give you any error?

Comment: @MichaelVayvala: No, no error is printed; the output just differs. I've edited the question to clarify that.

Comment: yeah, now I can see that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The slice start and stop arguments are equal, so the `next(it)` call on the xrange raises `StopIteration`:

```
>>> s = slice(3, 3, None)
>>> it = iter(xrange(s.start or 0, s.stop or 200, s.step or 1))
>>> next(it)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

and the `slice()` generator function immediately terminates. This is only logical, the `xrange()` function is not going to produce any numbers in that case.

The `itertools` documentation is *illustrative*, and not meant to be complete. You've found one edgecase where the sample Python code does not work the same way that the C implementation works.

To make the Python code work for this case as well, catch the `StopIteration` exception, and test for the edgecase explicitly in the loop:

```
def islice(iterable, *args):
    s = slice(*args)
    it = iter(xrange(s.start or 0, s.stop or 200, s.step or 1))
    try:
        nexti = next(it)
        consume = False
    except StopIteration:
        if s.start < 1:
            return
        nexti = s.start - 1
        consume = True
    for i, element in enumerate(iterable):
        if i == nexti:
            if consume:
                return
            yield element
            nexti = next(it)
```

The Python sample code uses a `slice()` object to make the code more compact and easier to read; the C code does its own start, stop and step parsing, and handles the count itself instead of delegating to `xrange()`, and thus doesn't run into this edgecase.

Comment: Thx, your version of islice is working. But may i ask why you use return ? It return None?  If it return None, how did the next() process?

Comment: @michaelyin: This is a generator function; `return` ends the generator (causing it to raise `StopIteration`).

Comment: The point of the return is to end the generator, not to return a value. You can't anyway; a generator function produces results with `yield`.

Comment: Note that `next(islice(numbers, 3, 3))` (so no default) raises `StopIteration`; it is the second argument to the `next()` function, a default return value, that suppresses that exception and returns the default instead. The `consume()` method sets the default to `None` but it matters little what the default is; the point is to suppress the exception, the return value is  ignored.